# C# access database error

Tags: c#, ms-access

This code when used in MS-Access is running and updating in property, ***but when using through database it's giving syntax error***

```
string item = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

string h="update Follow_Date set Current_Date='" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToLongDateString() + "', Current_Time='" + dateTimePicker3.Value.ToLongTimeString() + "', Type='" +
                            comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "', Remarks='" +
                            textBox1.Text + "', Next_Follow_Date='" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToLongDateString()+ "' where Follow_Id='" +
                            item.ToString() +"'";

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\lernovo\Documents\JDB.mdb");

con.Open();

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(h, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Error is `syntax error`.

Comment: Try to use parameterized queries.

Comment: I would strongly advice you to move away from the approach of using string concatenation when creating sql queries. This is a sql injection disaster waiting to happen

Comment: What syntax error? What the error line says?

Answer (score 3):

```
string item = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

string h="update Follow_Date set @Current_Date, @Current_Time, @Type, @Remarks, @Next_Follow_Date where @Follow_Id";

try
{
Using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\lernovo\Documents\JDB.mdb"))
{
  con.Open();

  Using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(h, con))
  {    
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Current_Date", dateTimePicker1.Value.ToLongDateString());
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Current_Time", dateTimePicker3.Value.ToLongTimeString());
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Remarks", textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Type", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Next_Follow_Date", dateTimePicker2.Value.ToLongDateString());
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Follow_Id", item.ToString());
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
}
catch(SQLException ex)
{
System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message, ex.StackaTrace)
}
```

You're not closing your Database connection and try to use Parameter instead of concatenation(Probe to SQL Injection).

Catch your error message and it trace it using StackTrace.  Try to use `Using` statement to dispose object properly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a trivial mistake...

You must have to open the db connection before executing queries on it..

```
conn=new conn(db param);
try
{
  conn.open()
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  e.getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Not downvoting but he have already opened the connection. See the question properly.

Comment: sir it's writtent con.Open()